# setTimeout in actionscript 2

Tags: flash, loops, settimeout, setinterval, actionscript-2

I'm using this

```
var timer2 = setTimeout(checkValue2, 2000);
```

as a frame action in Frame 2, which then triggers checkValue2 which is a piece of function in Frame 1 where all the _global. variables are as well.

```
clearTimeout(timer2);
gotoAndStop(3);     //goto lvl3 - throw
addStage3();
```

so it'd then goto Frame 3, but, the problem is even after clearing, the frame animation still loops every 2 seconds, regardless whether i'm using setTimeout or setInterval. Do you might know of any other way where what I need is, after 2 seconds in Frame 2, it'd then move to Frame 3, which I don't want it to go anywhere yet.

am i doing something wrong here :(

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to use clearTimeout() at all, because [setTimeout() executes a function only once](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000602.html#159267).  Are you sure you've stopped the animation after calling setTimeout in frame 2 in the first place?

**EDIT**

Your movie probably loops at a later point, so that frame2 is executed over and over again.  To find the cause of the problem, do this:

1. Add an event listener to frame 1 of your main timeline:

   ```
   onEnterFrame = function () : Void { 
           trace ("current: " + _currentFrame) 
       }
   ```
2. Run your program and check the trace output: At which point does the loop occur?
3. If the loop always happens at the same frame: Check that frame's content and see if you have any gotoAndPlay(), or play() in it.  Also, re-check that your stop() calls are not nested within function declarations or somehow unreachable (e.g. within if/else statements which never execute, or after some other code that would stop the script or jump to another frame).
4. If the loop happens erratically: See if you have any ActionScript that executes randomly or at timed intervals.  btw: You can use the MovieExplorer window to find all AS within your FLA.

Comment: you mean by "stop()" ? I can't do that as there are animations that are needs to run in the frame as well. Or am i understanding you wrongly?

Comment: You understand correctly.  A stop() on the main timeline will only stop the main timeline, but not any animations within other MovieClips.

Comment: If you keep looping frame 1 and 2, you will call the setTimeout() frame action on each loop - no wonder this doesn't work.

Comment: weltraumpirat; thankx for replying :) and yes I do have a stop on every frame, even the gotoAndStop(3) also has a stop. There is a stop at frame2 and frame3 already.

Comment: Hm...  Do you get any error messages?  Are you using the content debugger plugin?  You could also add a trace in the checkValue2 function to see if this is executed at all.

Comment: Nope i don't have the plugin but, I did add a trace and according to the trace is that, every 2 seconds my checkValue2 happens. I placed a trace in there and not only that, the whole point is after 2 seconds in frame 2, moving to frame 3 will add a ball onto the stage, and every 2 seconds, i'd have an addition of balls :(

Comment: Add another trace just before the setTimeout() call.  If the output is sent more than once, your movie somehow loops back to the beginning. Unless there are any error messages, which would indicate that some scripts might have been aborted and causing erratic behavior, you will have to check if anything else in your FLA moves the playhead back there.

Comment: weltraumpirat; i did what you said, adding another trace before the call and yes miraculously that trace would happen again and again. Could there be a control which loops the player? I enabled simple frame actions as well as live view but still the same thing

Comment: I've changed my answer and added some debugging advice.  You know what problem to look for - good luck!

Comment: weltraumpirat, i don't know if i'm too newb to know, but is that AS3? cause I'm using as2 and it seems to give me an error of A type identifier is expected after the ':'. error

Comment: weltraumpirate; so sorry such a late reply. But, i'm getting "current frame undefined" hmm I'm on the verge of giving up on this hmm

Comment: my bad again - it should have been _currentFrame.

Comment: oops, i should have replied earlier, ya i managed to get it to show currentFrame, but, it seems that the movie goes to frame 3 as a trace in the frame 3 did appear, but, shortly after that it'd bounce back to frame 2 that is why its there and i'm very sure that there's no calls or stops that are out of place hmmm

Comment: There has to be something. Otherwise it wouldn't do that.  Try this: Create a new FLA, add only what's necessary to create the frame changing behavior, then see what happens.  If it works, gradually add the rest of your stuff, until it breaks - then you have the problem isolated.